# Unable to expand list view selector

Tags: list-view, backup, restore, list-view-web-part

I have restored a **SharePoint - 80 application** backup on a new server and mapped the existing domain name to this server.
The default list view selector does not show the available pre-defined views/pages, but returns the `500 Internal Server Error - http://SERVER_NAME/SUB_SITE/_layouts/vsmenu.aspx?List=LIST_NAME...` error instead (captured via Firebug).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by associating the existing public domain name with the restored SharePoint - 80 application.

When accessing all the SharePoint pages (and the problematic functional elements as well) via the `http://HOSTNAME_HERE/` address, everything operates properly.

When accessing all the SharePoint pages (and the problematic functional elements as well) via the `http://PUBLIC_DOMATIN_DAME/` address, this issue occurs.

I am going to research this issue separately.